# How do I handle "cancel" intent when already in a dialog?

Tags: node.js, botframework

In Microsoft Bot Framework, I already started a conversation and have some intent running, let's say "login", but then while I ask the user for username or password, he might say "cancel that" or "cancel login", how do I get this intent: "cancel" and how do I handle it by cancelling out of the current dialog?

```
// Login Dialog
bot.dialog('login', [
    (session:Builder.Session) => {
        Builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What\'s your account email?');
    },
    (session:Builder.Session, results: any) => {
        session.dialogData.email = results.response;
        Builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What\'s your password?');
    },
    (session:Builder.Session, results: any) => {
        session.dialogData.passWord = results.response;
        CheckAccountLogin(session, session.dialogData.email,session.dialogData.passWord)
            .then((result:boolean)=>{
                if(result === true){
                    session.send('Login Successful');
                    session.userData.loginSuccessful = true;
                    session.userData.email = session.dialogData.email;
                }else{
                    session.userData.loginSuccessful = false;
                }
                session.endDialog();
            });
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is to use the built in cancel event.  Luis would still work.  This is based on Javier's answer:

```
// Setup Luis Recognizer first:
const LuisModelUrl = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/' + LuisID + '?subscription-key=' + LuisKey;
var recognizer = new Builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

// Dialog definition
bot.dialog('login', [
    (session:Builder.Session) => {
        // Your dialog stuff here
    }
]).cancelAction(
    "Cancel", "What would you like to do next?",
    {
        matches: "Cancel",
        confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your dialog.  Are you ure?"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

You can basically register a `CancelIntent` recognizer that will cause the conversation to forwarded the dialog you want then triggered. For example:

```
bot.recognizer(new builder.RegExpRecognizer( 
    "CancelIntent", 
    { en_us: /^(cancel|nevermind)/i, ja_jp: /^(キャンセル)/ })
);
```

This uses a regular expression to detect when the user wants to cancel, and one way to cancel the current dialog would be just to end the conversation:

```
bot.dialog('CancelDialog', function (session) {
    session.endConversation("Ok, cancelling loggin.");
}).triggerAction({ matches: 'CancelIntent' });
```

Notice that the code above tells the bot framework to end the conversation, so the login dialog will end thus cancelling the action.

Here are some useful samples too: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js

**Edit**

To set up a Luis intent recognizer you first need to remove the previously registered RegexRecognizer and then create a new instance of the LuisRecognizer by doing:

```
// Make sure you add code to validate these fields
var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

// Create a recognizer that gets intents from LUIS, and add it to the bot
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
```

And then register the Luis recognizer with:

```
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
```

Your CancelDialog should look the same, it will match the intent with the `triggerAction.matches`:

```
bot.dialog('CancelDialog', function (session) {
    session.endConversation("Ok, cancelling loggin.");
}).triggerAction({ matches: 'CancelIntent' });
```

Once you have that setup create the `CancelIntent` in your Luis App, add some sample utterances to it (at least three) and the conversation should automatically forward to the CancelDialog once the CancelIntent is detected.

There's more info about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Is it possible to Microsoft Luis cognitive recognition for the recognizer?  It would be way more accurate than regex recognizer.

Comment: Yes you can! I updated my answer based on your comment